# Error "Array to string conversion" in relationship belogsToMany in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-8, store, has-and-belongs-to-many

I save data reqNumber in master table

in model product
`public function orders(){ return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class); }`

in model order
 `public function products(){ return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class); }`

in controller

```
`    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user=auth()->user();
    $data=$request->validate([
        'products'=>'required',
        'reqNumber'=>'required',
    ]);

   $order=Order::create([
         'employee_id'=>$user->id
     ]);
  
    $order->products()->attach( 
        $data['products'],
        ['reqNumber'=>$data['reqNumber']]
    );
     return response('success order');
}`
```

Comment: by sync() do not save reqNumber

Answer (score 1):

Does reqNumber need to be wrapped in an array?

Comment: yes.example data reqNumber is:  array:3 [
  0 => "50"
  1 => "100"
  2 => "50"
]

Comment: So you probs, depeneding on your db structure, need to json_encode that array.

Comment: No, I want to save each one

Comment: what an index to a column referenced in array?

Comment: This is the number of products requested from the order

Comment: So you want your columns to be 0, 1, 2 and the values to be 50, 100, 50

Comment: product_id is foreign key

Comment: No ,columns is product_id ,order_id ,request_number

Comment: Could you share the order class then. It is really difficult if you don't share that.

Comment: class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=['category_id','storekeeper_id','employee_id'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }

   public function products(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'order_product');
   }

   public function storekeeper(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'storekeeper_id');
   }
   public function employee(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'employee_id');
    }
}

Comment: okay wait up what is the error you are getting? just not being able to store to the db?

Comment: yes when store to db error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: json_encode($array);

Comment: Multiple products must be stored in multiple rows  this is table master relationship many to many

Comment: Then pass it with the keys ['category_id' => $array[$index], storekeeper_id => $array[$index], employee_id => $array[$index]]

Comment: unless you are passing an associative array laravel has no idea where to store the id in the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243408/discussion-between-morteza-kia-and-alex-mac).